# Override .env with inline arguments

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, env-cmd

Is it possible to override the variables inside .env on run or build?

Content of the .env file

```
REACT_APP_REGIONALIZED_BASE_API_URL=http://hello-default.net
```

Command script in package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start:production": "env-cmd -f .env react-scripts start",
}
```

Sample start command executed in terminal or even in ci/cd pipeline where you have instances based on regions

```
REACT_APP_REGIONALIZED_BASE_API_URL=http://hello-eu.net yarn start:production
```

So, instead of having a build with api url `http://hello-default.net`, it should have `http://hello-eu.net`

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the [alternative] solution I discovered. Just need to add `--no-override` argument. This will prevent replacing of the already set variable. Also applicable with multiple env files.

```
"scripts": {
  "start:production": "env-cmd --no-override -f .env react-scripts start",
}
```